# Random Forest "Feature Importance"

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I am currently working on Random Forest Classifier. One of the parameters of Random Forest Classifier is "Criterion" which has 2 options : Gini or Entropy. Low value of Gini is preferred and high value of Entropy is preferred. By default, gini is criterion for Random Forest Classifier.

There is an attribute called `feature_importances_` provided by sklearn, where we get the values of the attributes/features provided. By using we can select some features and eliminate some using "threshold and SelectFromModel"

My doubt is that, on what basis these `feature_importances_` are calculated? Assume default criterion "Gini" is available. If I assume the `feature_importances_` are "Gini Importances" then low value is preferred, but in feature importances, high values are preferred

Answer (score 2):

`features_importances_` always output the importance of the features. **If the value is bigger, more important is the feature**, don't take in consideration gini or entropy criterion, it doesn't matter. Criterion is used to build the model. Feature importance is applied after the model is trained, you only "analyze" and observe which values have been more relevant in your trained model.

Moreover, you will see that all `features_importances_` sums to 1, so the importance is seen as a percentage too.

Since RandomForest is formed by several trees, feature importances are averaged over all the trees.

Comment: If I select only the most important features and ignore the less important features using "SelectFromModel" then the model is built using the selected features only, right ?

Comment: Exactly! You are completely right! On more thing, when you reduce features, you will probably obtain a smaller accuracy. Then, you have to evaluate which model you prefer: 1) 95% accuracy with 100 features or 2) 90% accuracy with 5 features. (These are invented numbers of course). Depending on your problem/ application you should decided which models suits better.